# How to send email using python in outlook with recipient as microsoft mail?

Tags: python, email, outlook, win32com

I'm having issue with sending an email out with my outlook. Every email address are like 'xxx@example.com', for my case, it's just names without a full email, and python don't accept names only, and I can't send out email. Please assist.

```
import win32com.client

olMailItem = 0x0
obj = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
newMail = obj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
newMail.Subject = "test"
newMail.Body = "test"
newMail.To = "Vick Peh"

newMail.Send()
```

Comment: Is it mandatory to send the email using your Outlook account or can you use your SMTP server to send the email? I'm telling you this, because it seems like you are using a painful way of sending emails ;).

Comment: Yes, it's a need to use outlook else, I would have use smtplib :( 
It's for company purposes, thus, trying to find out anyway that I could automate my code and send the file automatically to the receiver.

Comment: Yea, a very painful way to do it. Only if I'm given an actual SMTP account to send it.

Comment: Please check this page: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2004-August/002239.html they implement a function called makeentry, which could be useful to resolve names, and convert them to email addresses.

Answer (score 0):

If you or Outlook do not know the email addresses, you cannot send.

If you have names only, Outlook should be able to resolve the name if it is in one of the address books - call newMail.Recipients.ResolveAll() before sending the message.

Comment: It is not detecting my contact in my address books. It keep shows me an error:

return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(61557, LCID, 1, (24, 0), (),)
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, u'Microsoft Outlook', u'Outlook does not recognize one or more names. ', None, 0, -2147467259), None)

Comment: Does Outlook resolve the name if you type it in the To edit box and hit Ctrl+K?

Comment: Outlook does detect the name straight when it to the TO box.
I solved the issue by my comment above (:
Cheers~

Answer (score 0):

If your address is @ your other address, try to right click and save as your personal address first. 
From there, you'll be able to retrieve the 'Internet Email' for the recipient.
Copy and paste the 'Internet Email' and TADA~